# Is there a way to have a hover effect on a menu using streamlit-antd-components?

Tags: python, css, streamlit

I have a question regarding the python library of streamlit-antd-components(sac).
I am trying to build a menu using streamlit's Sidebar feature, and using sac's menu as follows:

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit-antd-components as sac

st.markdown('<style>' + open('./style.css').read() + '</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

with st.sidebar:
    sac.menu = (_menu items and features_)
```

the style.css file is as follows:

```
header[data-testid="stHeader"]{
    display:none;
}

section[data-testid="stSidebar"] {
    height: 100%;
    min-width:95px !important;
    width: 95px !important;
    transform:translateX(0px);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

section[data-testid="stSidebar"]:hover{
    min-width: 280px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div[data-testid="stSidebarUserContent"] {
    height: 100%;
    width: 280px !important;
    transform:translateX(0px);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height:2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    padding-top: 60px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

**div[data-testid:"element-container"] > iframe > html > body > div > ul > li > span:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: none;
}**

button[kind="header"] {
    display: none;
}

div[data-testid="collapsedControl"]{
    display: none;
}
```

And this is the html of the streamlit website where the hover feature happens and that I am trying to change, please check image attached:
[html for the element to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rGUW.png)

Question is what can I add to the css file in order to make the text of the menu disappear, reappear when hovering and make the selection box of the menu item be less width when not hovering on it?